# Google Static Maps API in Google Drive (Docs) Spreadsheet

Tags: api, google-maps, google-sheets

I am trying to pull an image using the **Google Static Maps** API into a Google Drive spreadsheet. It seems to, mostly, work. However, it will seem to randomly not work for some zip codes. However, if my manually type those zip codes into my address bar on the browser, it works fine. Here is my code in the cell:

> =image("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=50x50&markers=color:green|size:tiny|"&E10&"&markers=color:red|size:tiny|"&B1&"&sensor=false")

Cells E10 and B1 have zip codes in them. If I vary B1, some zip codes don't work. Specifically, B1 = 20001 and E10 = 22408 doesn't work. However:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=50x50&markers=color:green|size:tiny|22408&markers=color:red|size:tiny|20001&sensor=false
```

in the address bar of my browser works perfectly fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've ran into the same problem. For me it doesn't work at all - I have a column with town/place names (UK) and I only ever get `#N/A (no image was found...)`. As you said, opening the URL in a browser works just fine.

Comment: In fact I'm surprised it works for you at all, I've stripped marker info leaving only required arguments in their simplest forms and I still get no map in the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've been able to get this to work is by shortening the URL using http://goo.gl Pasting that URL in the spreadsheet will work.

```
=image("http://goo.gl/dOmcVP", 1)
```